# AngularJS - UI Router: Get template url from within the template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm creating states via ui-router, and attaching them to the same controller. (although obviously different instances of that controllers are initialized)

Inside of that controller, I'd like to know the name of the template it was initialized for.

My idea was to somehow pass to that controller properties in the stateProvider (ui-sref doesn't solve opening the browser with a deep link), but from my searches so far it appears it can't be done.

I can't simply check the name of the current state, since I'm working with multiple views.

I'm working with the same controller for multiple states and views, the controller can act accordingly as soon as he can know the name of the template he's attached to.

Here's how I create my states and views:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    var controller = 'textFile';
    var base = 'templates';
    var views = ['home', 'about'];

    for (var i = 0; i < views.length; i++)
    {
        var view = views[i];

        $stateProvider.state(view, {
            url: '/' + view,
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl: base + '/header.html',
                    controller: controller
                },
                'page': {
                    templateUrl: base + '/' + view + '.html',
                    controller: controller
                },
                'footer': {
                    templateUrl: base + '/footer.html',
                    controller: controller
                }
            }
        });
    }
}]);
```

I need to be able to know in textFile for instance if it's attached to header.html, footer.html, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a resolve, so that you can access the unique data for each controller instance. For example:

```
$stateProvider.state(view, {
    url: '/' + view,
    views: {
        'header': {
            templateUrl: base + '/header.html',
            controller: 'textFile',
            resolve: {
                viewName: function() { return 'header'; }
            }
        },
        'page': {
            templateUrl: base + '/' + view + '.html',
            controller: 'textFile',
            resolve: {
                viewName: function() { return 'page'; }
            }
        },
        'footer': {
            templateUrl: base + '/footer.html',
            controller: 'textFile',
            resolve: {
                viewName: function() { return 'footer'; }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can access the value in your controller:

```
.controller('textFile', function($scope, viewName){
    console.log(viewName);
});
```

Comment: Cool idea. I have never before thought of a legitimate real-world use for view-level resolves.